# I am unable update ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates

when I'm trying to update through terminal I'm getting the following error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I am not sure if it is due to virus or any other reason.

Comment: Do you use sudo to get root rights? Like "sudo apt-get upgrade"

Comment: Did you have something like synaptics, or update manager open at the time?

Answer (score 0):

Kill any programs like update-manager,software center. Still if the problem exists, remove the lock file. `rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock` and try the command you were trying again.

Also, surely there is no virus in your system, Keep Calm !!!